# Getting erroneous values in solving system of linear equations in Fortran

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran

I tried making a program for calculating the solution of 3rd order matrix using gaussian elimination method with partial pivoting but am getting erroneous values. I'm not able to understand the reason. Please help.

GAUSS ELIMINATION: I solve the equations by forming a matrix. Once I form that matrix, I subtract row 1 from rows 2,3 in a way that makes 1st elements of rows2,3 zero(by multiplying and dividing with required constants i.e. by elementary row operations in matrices) and then subtract row 2 from 3. Note, before each such subtraction I make sure that I don't have to divide by zero anytime.

CODE:

```
program solving_three_equations
implicit none

real, allocatable :: a(:,:)
real, allocatable :: y(:)
integer i,j,n
real temp,z,l,m,w,q,temp_y

n=3
allocate(a(n,n))
allocate(y(n))

do i=1,n
read(*,*)(a(i,j),j=1,3)
end do

do i=1,n
read(*,*)y(i)
end do

q=max( abs(a(1,1)), abs(a(2,1)), abs(a(3,1)) )

if(q==abs(a(1,1))) then
goto 100

else if(q== abs(a(2,1))) then

do i=1,3
temp=a(1,i)
a(1,i)=a(2,i)
a(2,i)=temp
temp_y=y(1)
y(1)=y(2)
y(2)=temp_y
end do

else

do i=1,3
temp=a(1,i)
a(1,i)=a(3,i)
a(3,i)=temp
temp_y=y(1)
y(1)=y(3)
y(3)=temp_y
end do

100 end if

do i=2,3

    do j=1,3
    
    a(i,j)= a(i,j)-(a(1,j)*a(i,1))/a(1,1)
    y(i)=(y(i)-((y(1)*a(i,1))/a(1,1)))
    
    end do
end do


w=max( abs(a(2,2)), abs(a(3,2)) )
if(w==abs(a(2,2))) then
goto 200

else

do i=2,3
temp=a(2,i)
a(2,i)=a(3,i)
a(3,i)=temp
temp_y=y(2)
y(2)=y(3)
y(3)=temp_y
end do

200 end if

i=3
do j=1,3
    
    a(i,j)= a(i,j)-(a(2,j)*a(3,2))/a(2,2)
    y(i)=(y(i)-((y(2)*a(3,2))/a(2,2)))
    
end do

z=(y(3)/a(3,3))
m=( (y(2)-a(2,3)*z)/a(2,2) )
l=( (y(1)-(a(1,3)*z)-(a(1,2)*m) )/a(1,1) )

print*, "z= ",z
print*, "y= ",m
print*, "x= ",l

endprogram solving_three_equations
```

Further, as is visible, this method is very difficult to extend to a general case of n equations and n variables.

**So, is there a better way to do this for general nxn Matrix?**

I used the value of matrix a, array y as:

```
    1  2  4  
a=  2  4  7  
    3  3  9  

y=   7
    13
    15
```

which should yield x=1, y=1, z=1 as the answer.

Comment: For dense linear algebra use LAPACK - http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ - SGESV is probably what you want http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/db8/group__real_g_esolve_ga3b05fb3999b3d7351cb3101a1fd28e78.html

Comment: I know the algebra of the problem well, it's just that the program I made using that algebra doesn't work. And I am not able to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Follow @IanBush's advice, use LAPACK.  Otherwise, you haven't supplied us with the values you use for the matrix `a` or vector `y`.  Additionally, while I do not fall into the cult that `goto` must be avoided at all cost (as `goto` does have its uses), your use of `goto` here is a poster child for a poor use case.

Comment: @evets thanks for the advice, I have edited the question to include the values too. And I do apologize for the goto use, should have used **continue** instead.

Comment: As this is a trivial set of equations, you likely would benefit from solving them in reduce matrix form by hand and compare each step with intermediate output from your program.  It also be beneficial to inspect the final reduced matrix to see if the reduction makes sense.

Comment: Your scaling and subtraction step is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your scaling and subtraction steps are wrong.  Printing intermediate values would help you debug the situation.  For the first scaling and subtraction you need to use

```
do i = 2, 3
   y(i) = y(i) - y(1) * a(i,1) / a(1,1)
   do j = 3, 1, -1
      a(i,j) = a(i,j) - (a(1,j) * a(i,1)) / a(1,1)
   end do
end do
```

For the second, use

```
i=3
y(i) = y(i) - y(2) * a(3,2) / a(2,2)
do j = 3, 1, -1 
   a(i,j) = a(i,j) - a(2,j) * a(3,2) / a(2,2)
end do
```

Note, I removed the excessive use of parentheses.

Comment: thanks, it worked. But how do I extend this to a general nxn matrix?

Comment: Of course, it works.  I won't have posted it otherwise. :-)  As to the nxn matrix case, see the comments about LAPACK.  If you think you want to do better, then don't unroll the outer loop that exchanges the rows.